# How to use Boolean OR inside a regex

Tags: python, regex, parsing, boolean-logic

I want to use a regex to find a substring, followed by a variable number of characters, followed by any of several substrings.

an re.findall of

```
"ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAGGATT"
```

should give me:

```
['ATGTCAGGTAA', 'ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAG', 'ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAG']
```

I have tried all of the following without success:

```
import re
string2 = "ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAGGATT"
re.findall('(ATG.*TAA)|(ATG.*TAG)', string2)
re.findall('ATG.*(TAA|TAG)', string2)
re.findall('ATG.*((TAA)|(TAG))', string2)
re.findall('ATG.*(TAA)|(TAG)', string2)
re.findall('ATG.*(TAA)|ATG.*(TAG)', string2)
re.findall('(ATG.*)(TAA)|(ATG.*)(TAG)', string2)
re.findall('(ATG.*)TAA|(ATG.*)TAG', string2)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: findall: Return a list of all **non-overlapping** matches in the string.

Comment: As a sidenote, `ATG.*(TAA|TAG)` will only match the longest possible string. That's because the `*` operator is greedy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not super-easy, because a) you want overlapping matches, and b) you want greedy and non-greedy and everything inbetween.

As long as the strings are fairly short, you can check every substring:

```
import re
s = "ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAGGATT"
p = re.compile(r'ATG.*TA[GA]$')

for start in range(len(s)-6):  # string is at least 6 letters long
    for end in range(start+6, len(s)):
        if p.match(s, pos=start, endpos=end):
            print(s[start:end])
```

This prints:

```
ATGTCAGGTAA
ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAG
ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAG
```

Since you appear to work with DNA sequences or something like that, make sure to check out [Biopython](http://biopython.org), too.

Comment: Interesting approach. Time complexity is O(N^3) right?

Comment: It should be O(n^2), unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Extracting all the substrings is O(N^3) on its own (O(N^2) substrings, and O(N) characters copied into each).  If someone needs to use this for real, better to respell it:  compile the regexp, and use its `.match()` method.  That accepts `pos` and `endpos` slice indices, so that you don't have to create any substring objects (and, of course, the expense of compiling the regexp is paid only once).

Comment: @TimPeters I thought I had read somewhere that compiling regexes didn't really help much because the interpreter is usually compiling it anyways? But I'll take your word for it. I adapted your suggestions for the answer.

Comment: CPython maintains a cache mapping recently used regexp strings to their compiled regexp objects, but that's not the real point - the real point is that `re.match()` doesn't accept slice indices, only `regexp_object.match()` does.  Using slice indices instead wholly avoids the expense of creating O(N^2) substring objects.

Comment: However, it breaks if

Answer (score 0):

I like the accepted answer just fine :-)  That is, I'm adding this for info, not looking for points.

If you have heavy need for this, trying a match on `O(N^2)` pairs of indices may soon become unbearably slow.  One improvement is to use the `.search()` method to "leap" directly to the only starting indices that can possibly pay off.  So the following does that.

It also uses the `.fullmatch()` method so that you don't have to artificially change the "natural" regexp (e.g., in your example, no need to add a trailing `$` to the regexp - and, indeed, in the following code doing so would no longer work as intended).  Note that `.fullmatch()` was added in Python 3.4, so this code also requires Python 3!

Finally, this intends to generalize the `re` module's `finditer()` function/method.  While you don't need match objects (you just want strings), they're far more generally applicable, and returning a generator is often friendlier than returning a list too.

So, no, this doesn't do exactly what you want, but does things from which you can *get* what you want, in Python 3, faster:

```
def finditer_overlap(regexp, string):
    start = 0
    n = len(string)
    while start <= n:
        # don't know whether regexp will find shortest or
        # longest match, but _will_ find leftmost match
        m = regexp.search(string, start)
        if m is None:
            return
        start = m.start()
        for finish in range(start, n+1):
            m = regexp.fullmatch(string, start, finish)
            if m is not None:
                yield m
        start += 1
```

Then, e.g.,

```
import re
string2 = "ATGTCAGGTAAGCTTAGGGCTTTAGGATT"
pat = re.compile("ATG.*(TAA|TAG)")
for match in finditer_overlap(pat, string2):
    print(match.group())
```

prints what you wanted in your example.  The other ways you tried to write a regexp should also work.  In this example it's faster because the second time around the outer loop `start` is 1, and `regexp.search(string, 1)` fails to find another match, so the generator exits at once (so skips checking `O(N^2)` other index pairs).